# Creating a Kubernetes Dashboard Token

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm trying to follow the instructions at https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md to create a Kubernetes Dashboard token.  However, when I run the specified command, I get an error

```
% kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user
Error: must specify one of -f and -k

error: unknown command "token admin-user"
See 'kubectl create -h' for help and examples
```

If I jump back [in the doc history](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/commit/f78bd53d7561eb614308b1aff5a134668244f2a4#diff-8c263c6ea3af03864ae35dfca688964ee8b03f118a59b904b409c09a34b1309f), I see a different, more verbose command that I can run

```
% kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/admin-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o go-template="{{.data.token | base64decode}}"
```

This seems to work OK and PR for the doc change mentions "version 1.24" but doesn't mention what piece of software version 1.24 refers to (`kubectl`? The Dashboard? Kuberenetes itself? `kind`? Something else?)

So what's going on with that first command?  Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a new feature in kubernetes 1.24, your cluster and `kubectl` must be running <1.24 version of Kubernetes, causing the issue. See the change log below:

> kubectl create token can now be used to request a service account
> token, and permission to request service account tokens is added to
> the edit and admin RBAC roles (#107880, @liggitt)

Another snippet showing more relevant info:

> Kubectl changes:
>
> Adds a command to kubectl to request a bound service account token.
> This will help ease the transition from scraping generated service
> account tokens with commands like kubectl get secret "$(kubectl get
> serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')"

Both server and client must be running 1.24 or newer, something like below:

```
kubectl version --output=json
{
  "clientVersion": {
    "major": "1",
    "minor": "24",
    "gitVersion": "v1.24.0",
    "gitCommit": "4ce5a8954017644c5420bae81d72b09b735c21f0",
    "gitTreeState": "clean",
    "buildDate": "2022-05-03T13:46:05Z",
    "goVersion": "go1.18.1",
    "compiler": "gc",
    "platform": "linux/amd64"
  },
  "kustomizeVersion": "v4.5.4",
  "serverVersion": {
    "major": "1",
    "minor": "24",
    "gitVersion": "v1.24.2",
    "gitCommit": "f66044f4361b9f1f96f0053dd46cb7dce5e990a8",
    "gitTreeState": "clean",
    "buildDate": "2022-06-15T14:15:38Z",
    "goVersion": "go1.18.3",
    "compiler": "gc",
    "platform": "linux/amd64"
  }
}
```

check this for more info: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/107880

Comment: Thank you @P -- one follow up question if you have a moment. Is this a problem that my _cluster_ is running 1.24, or that my version of kubectl isn't 1.24?  Or both? (I'm running a cluster via kind in a very "this is all magic to me I'm still learning" sort of way).

Comment: you may run `kubectl get node -owide` to see the version used in your cluster., it's likely that you are not running version ``1.24`` and using something lower than 1.24.

Comment: also, only using the latest kubectl client on older clusters may not help.

Answer (score 9):

If your version is lower than 1.24, please run the following command.

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/admin-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o go-template="{{.data.token | base64decode}}"
```

This works in my case. Thanks.

Comment: Adding an `echo` to the end of the command makes copying the token easier:
`kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/admin-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o go-template="{{.data.token | base64decode}}"; echo`